# Depth first search - returned path from one vertex of a graph to another includes unnecessary vertices

Tags: python, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

In Kent D. Lee's textbook, Data Structures and Algorithms with Python, there is a problem using depth-first search. According to the book, I must:

> Write a program to find a path between vertex 9 and 29 in the graph shown in Fig. 7.9. Be sure to print the path (i.e. the sequence of vertices) that must be traversed in the path between the two vertices.

The code is given below:

```py
def graphDFS(G, start, goal):
    def adjacent(current, edges):
        adj_list = []

        for e in edges:
            if current == e[0]:
                adj_list.append(e[1])

        return adj_list

    stack = []
    visited = set()
    path = []

    stack.append(start)

    while not len(stack) == 0:
        current = stack.pop()
        visited.add(current)
        path.append(current)

        if current == goal:
            return path
            # return True  # or return path to goal perhaps

        for v in adjacent(current, G[1]):
            if v not in visited:
                stack.append(v)

    return []
```

The link to an image of the directed graph is given here: [(See Fig. 9 for the graph)](https://kentdlee.github.io/CS2Plus/build/html/chap7/chap7.html#figures-from-text)

The path I currently have is `[9, 3, 2, 8, 13, 16, 17, 6, 24, 27, 29]`. When I checked my results in the end, though, the entire path is good except for that 6. My guess is that it has something to do with the stack that was used. Does anybody know what's wrong with my code?

Thanks! :D

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I was just looking for a way to store a proper path in a variable (e.g. a list). For example, if we had to traverse from 9 to 28 to 27 to 29, then I want to be able to somehow keep track of this path and print it out in the end as [28, 27].

Comment: Then just store current vertice (using dfs) in a separate list till you find goal vertice. That's it

Comment: The problem is that instead of giving me [28, 27] as I want, it gives me something like [18, 25, 28, 29, 20, 27]. So how could I store the correct ones instead of the ones that don't lead to the target?

Comment: Use global flag. Suppose DFS encounters start vertice then set it true. Now you should store current vertice only if flag is `true`. Once you encounter goal node you can set the flag as `false` and continue whole graph search or else you can even directly return as you got what you wanted. Well my Python is bad, if language wasn't constraint I would have answered it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways of tackling this problem. For one you could run BFS instead of DFS, or alternatively you could do some "hand wavy" stuff with a Disjoint Union Set (DSU) to find the path between two vertices in a graph.

Comment: I don't know how to use breadth-first search or a disjoint union set. Even then, my goal is to use depth-first search to solve this problem. Either way, thanks for your suggestion. I'll be sure to look up breadth-first search and DSU.